# Angular form Validation messages not appearing

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm missing something simple I am sure of it, but my form validation messages never appear in the following code.

```
<form name="loginform"  ng-controller="controllers.LoginController"  ng-submit="loginUser(loginform.$valid)" novalidate>
        <fieldset>
          <br/>
            <legend><h3>Account Login</h3></legend>

            <div class="{ 'has-error' : loginform.username.$invalid && !loginform.username.$pristine }">
                <label>Username:</label>
                 <input type="text" ng-model="username" name="username" placeholder="username"  class="form-control"   required><span   ng-show="loginform.username.$invalid && !loginform.username.$pristine" class="help-block">Required!</span>

            </div>
      <br/>         
            <div class="{ 'has-error' : loginform.password.$invalid && !loginform.password.$pristine }">
            <label>Password:</label> 
                <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control"  required><span   ng-show="loginform.password.$invalid && !loginform.password.$pristine" class="help-block">Required!</span>
            </div>


             <div class="form-group">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>

                 <a href="#" class="advanced-search-button submit-button" ng-disabled='!loginform.$valid' ng-click="loginUser(loginform.$valid)">Login</a>
            </div>


        </fieldset>
    </form>


controllers.LoginController = function ($scope, $location, AuthFactory, Page) {
'use strict';


$scope.username = null;
$scope.password = null;


$scope.loginUser = function (isValid) {
```

Comment: Any chance of a JSFiddle version to see it (not) working?

Answer (score 0):

The $pristine check was the problem... Here are the corrections...

```
 <form name="loginform"  ng-submit="loginUser(loginform.$valid)" novalidate>
        <fieldset>
          <br/>
            <legend><h3>Account Login</h3></legend>

            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : loginform.password.$invalid && submitted }">
                <label>Username:</label>
                 <input type="text" ng-model="username" name="username" placeholder="username"  class="form-control" ng-required="true"   required><span   ng-show="loginform.username.$invalid && submitted" class="help-block">Required!</span>

            </div>
      <br/>         
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : loginform.password.$invalid && submitted }">
            <label>Password:</label> 
                <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control"  required><span   ng-show="loginform.password.$invalid && submitted" class="help-block">Required!</span>
            </div>


             <div class="form-group">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>

                 <a href="#" class="advanced-search-button submit-button" ng-disabled='!loginform.$valid' ng-click="loginUser(loginform.$valid)">Login</a>
            </div>


        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application is form heavy, consider using this thirdparty [ngValidate](https://github.com/RijulB/ngValidate) module.

```
<input name="demo-field-1" ng-model="user.name" ng-validate="custom-strategy">
```

The directive will add a span to hold your error messages. You can define custom validation strategies and individual error messages.

[demo plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/T2imkFf1yYKPB2ljkYtR)